Trusted SSL certificate installed on intranet machine?
At my (large) company I am setting up a web server on an internal machine. I want the server to support SSL transparently. It can only be accessed by users on the VPN, and its name (foo.mycompany.com) is only resolved by the internal DNS on VPN. The machine can reach the Internet, if that helps.
The company provides a self-service certificate system, but (AFAICT) the certificates all chain to a trusted internal root certificate. This root certificate is automatically installed on machines that are managed by IT, but unmanaged machines which are on the VPN must manually install this certificate for the SSL to work. I'm trying to see if there's a safe, valid solution that does NOT involve forcing users with unmanaged machines to manually install a certificate.
I gather LetsEncrypt is not an option, since the server is not reachable from outside the VPN. Am I correct that this is how all other public trusted roots will behave, that if they cannot verify the server's identity, they will not provide a trusted certificate?
Is there any way for me to get a cert that will be trusted by all clients, without them manually installing the company's root certificate?


I gather LetsEncrypt is not an option, since the server is not reachable from outside the VPN. Am I correct that this is how all other public trusted roots will behave, that if they cannot verify the server's identity, they will not provide a trusted certificate?

In the first place, verifying the server's identity does not require reaching the server, because it's not really the server that is being verified at all – what CAs really certify is just the name (ownership or at least control thereof), with the control of an HTTP server behind that name being a proxy for it. But there are other ways to prove control of the domain name besides making a direct connection to a server.
For example, Let's Encrypt has supported DNS-based proofs for most of its lifetime, as an alternative to the HTTP check. You can get a certificate for any domain name that you can prove DNS control of (as long as you can automate the DNS updates).
Many other CAs (e.g. Sectigo) only validate the base domain, not individual subdomains, and once you go through the yearly DV procedure (which is also more commonly DNS-based these days) you can use that account to order certificates for any subdomain, even ones that don't exist in public DNS.
But since servers don't have an inherent identity, you can also externally point the domain name to a different IP address of another server (using DNS views) and have that server use HTTP validation to obtain the certificate, then automatically deploy it to the internal server.


Am I correct that this is how all other public trusted roots will behave, that if they cannot verify the server's identity, they will not provide a trusted certificate?

No. If you own the domain name, the CA will sell you a certificate for any name that you want.
Your IT probably already has a CA vendor that you can purchase certificates from, and are trusted by all endpoints.
